# Name for the following set of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I have the following set of polynomials defined by
$$P_n(x) = \sum^n_{k = 0} \frac{n!}{k!} x^k, \quad x \geqslant 0.$$
The first few are
\begin{align*}
P_0 (x) &= 1\\
P_1 (x) &= 1+x\\
P_2 (x) &= 2 + 2x + x^2\\
P_3 (x) &= 6 + 6x + 3x^2 + x^3\\
P_4 (x) &= 24 + 24x + 12 x^2 + 4x^3 + x^4
\end{align*}
It can readily be observed that
$$P'_n (x) = n P_{n - 1} (x), \quad n \geqslant 1.$$
I wish to know if these polynomials are widely known, and if so, do they have a special name?

If not, is it possible to find recurrence relation(s), a Rodrigues' formula, and a generating function for the polynomials?

**Note Added**: I know for the Hermite polynomials $H_n (x)$ that $H'_n (x) = 2n H_{n - 1} (x)$.

**Second Note Added**: Based on the second link Lucian provided, other than their name, I now have answers for the three questions I asked.

They are:

Recurrence relation: $P_{n + 1}(x) = (x + n + 1) P_n (x) - nx P_{n - 1}(x), 
\quad n \geqslant 1$.

Rodrigues' formula: $P_n (x) = (-1)^n \displaystyle{\frac{x^{n + 1}}{{\rm e}^{-x}} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \left (\frac{{\rm e}^{-x}}{x} \right )}$.

Generating function: $\displaystyle{\frac{{\rm e}^{xt}}{1 - t} = \sum^\infty_{n = 0} P_n (x) \frac{t^n}{n!}}$.

Comment: The observation strangely reminds me of Gamma except derivative is replaced with $P_{n+1}(x)$...

Comment: I know for the Hermite polynomials $H_n (x)$ one has $H'_n (x) = 2n H_{n - 1} (x)$.

Comment: omegadot, I think that's VERY relevant, and you might want to put in the post...

Comment: See [these](http://oeis.org/search?q=1,4,12,24,24) two [links](http://oeis.org/search?q=24,24,12,4,1).

Comment: Wolfram and others call that the Exponential Sum Function (without $n!$). Denoted $e_n(x)$ or $\exp_n(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

After Jack's comment, it seems that $$P_n(x)=e^x \,\Gamma (n+1,x)$$ match the expression so $$P_{n+1}(x)=\frac{\Gamma (n+2,x)}{\Gamma (n+1,x)}\,P_n(x)$$ Now, the name ?

Answer (score 1):

Upto an integer scalar multiple, $P_n(x)$ is the truncation of $e^x$.
It was proved by Schur that this polynomial is irreducible (cannot be factorized as product of lower degree polynomials with rational coefficients).
T N Shorey has  worked  in generalizing  this result. It will have results relevant to your quest.